Generate url from other layer inside my web api
So, i have a .net web api project with layers (Application, Infra...)
Inside my .net core web API, specifically inside application layer, i need to generate a url, this method is called by rabbitMQ consumer, like image below

Since the method is not called by the controller, i cant use HttpContext to get base url, right?
So, one solution is to save the fixed url in appsettings.json, but I wouldn't like to do it that way, is there a way to get the url from my API?
After generate the url, i need to send this url to other service integrations.

so , your Question is reach your API address in RabbitMQ consumer or next layer application layer? am i right?
